# In a local domain can I correct a DNS record by only changing the A record?

Tags: windows-server-2016, internal-dns

I added a server to my network using the same name of a previously decommissioned server.  But the new server has a new IP address.

I deleted the old computer in the AD and the new server added without issue.  But when I checked the DNS A record it still had the old IP.

If I edit the A record to update the IP address, are there any other locations that have to be edited?  I know that sometimes there can be other data remaining elsewhere in the records.

Or is there a better process that I should follow to get the DNS corrected?

Answer (score 2):

To keep things clean/simple, delete the A records for both servers.  Create a new A record for the new server.  Check your PTR records (reverse DNS) and confirm that the IP address you are using for the new server has a PTR record pointing to the host name of your new server.